# select file in Safari in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, safari, protractor

Executing this code in Safari doesn't work, but it works in chrome and firefox:

```
var pathToFile = path.resolve('./scripts', file);
element( by.css('input[ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)"]')).sendKeys(pathToFile);
```

In digging around it looks like it's not possible to interact with file inputs in this way in Protractor running on Safari. Does anyone know of a workaround in Safari to put a file path in an input?

Comment: Did you find a workaround?

Comment: I honestly don't remember. I haven't touched angular in years

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a leaky abstraction, which requires a Safari specific solution:

> I guess the workaround for those that really want to do file upload for SafariDriver would be not to do it natively via SafariDriver but by using external code libraries to perform the upload via HTTP/HTTPS (POST) requests (combining any other form data in addition to the file being uploaded/sent), then get response and check whether upload succeeded or not, then go back to SafariDriver code and navigate to next page to check upload succeeded or not, and/or to continue from there for the next steps in the automation.
>
> This approach would be similar to the file download method using HTTP requests externally that has been mentioned in various posts in WebDriver and Selenium user Google groups. Here, it's just the inverse, doing upload instead of download.
>
> Though if the upload requires a session (cookie), then you can extract Selenium session cookie and use with HTTP request. Or if session is stored with session ID in URL, extract that and pass along with HTTP request.

**References**

- [Selenium Issue 4220: The SafariDriver does not support file uploads](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/selenium-developer-activity/151pbyaezs/issue-8420-in-selenium-safaridriver-needs-support-for-webstorage)
- [How to upload file using Selenium when the file input is hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607453/1113772)
- [Access is denied error in IE while file uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286993/1113772)
- [Changing the value of input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375004/1113772)
- [Chrome file upload bug: on change event won't be executed twice with the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155136/1113772)
- [Selenium IDE 1.4.1 throwing security error when uploading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149403/1113772)
- [Dynamically submitting a file upload form in IE10 using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676945/1113772)